# How do I remove the three dots tab?

Tags: swiftui, tabview

So I created a tabview in SwiftUI but it keeps showing the 'three dots more' tab. How do I remove that?

TabView{

```
        Text("")
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "house")
                Text("Home")
        }
        Text("")
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
                Text("Search")
            }
        Text("")
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "plus")
                Text("Add")
            }
        Text("")
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "suit.heart")
                Text("Likes")
            }
        Text("")
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "person")
                Text("Profile")
            }

    }//end tabview
```

[image: My TabView]

Comment: This is not shown in latest Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Without more code it is not easy, to determine the reason for this behavior.

1. Check if the SceneDelegate window.rootcontroller points to your struct, where the TabView is located, not to the normal contentView
2. Replace the Textstrings with Views like:

   ```
   TabView{
      FirstView()
          .tabItem {
              Image(systemName: "house")
              Text("Home")
      }
   ```

   }
3. Check, that there is no Text between Tabview and the first TabItem, because the TabView interprets this as an additional Tabitem

   ```
   TabView{
       Text("this causes the error")
       FirstView()
           .tabItem {
               Image(systemName: "house")
               Text("Home")
       }
   ```

With these three tips your Tabbar should work [image: Tabbar behavior]

I'm working with Xcode 11.3

Comment: Your first sentence is a reason to close the question, not answer it. Ask for more code first. Do not guess at the intent: [answer]